# Maximum conneciton age for PostgreSQL on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Is there a way to set maximum connection age (maximum amount of time a connection can be used before it has to be recreated) for PostgreSQL connections in Ruby on Rails?

Edit: I need to make sure that no Postgres connection from my app to the bouncer lives for more than X minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres does not have a max connection age parameter. However, [pgbouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html) does—you can set up pgbouncer in front of Postgres and us the  client_idle_timeout parameter. However, that could cause some unexpected behavior (I think you may need to update your post and let us know what it is you’re trying to accomplish

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)